# Determine a generator system

Tags: linear-algebra

Consider the following subspace in $\mathbb{R}^4$: $W=\{(x-y+3z, 2x-y+3z+u, -x-3z+2u, x+3y-3z-2u)\in \mathbb{R}^4 : x,y,z,u \in \mathbb{R}, 2x - u = -y-z\}$
Determine the generator system in $W$.

First, let's rewrite the condition $2x - u = -y - z$ in terms of the variables $x, y, z,$ and $u$:

$$2x + y + z + u = 0$$

Now, we can express the vectors in $W$ using this equation:

$$(x - y + 3z, 2x - y + 3z + u, -x - 3z + 2u, x + 3y - 3z - 2u) =
(x, 2x, -x, x) + (-y, -y, 0, 3y) + (3z, 3z, -3z, 0) + (0, u, 2u, -2u)$$

By rearranging terms, we can rewrite this as:

$$x(1, 2, -1, 1) + y(-1, -1, 0, 3) + z(3, 3, -3, 0) + u(0, 1, 2, -2)$$

Is it correct?

Comment: You have made a minor mistake. The subspace $W$ is generated by $(1,2,-1,1),(-1,-1,0,3),(3,3,-3,-3)$, and $(0,1,2,-2)$. However, the vectors $(1,2,-1,1),(-1,-1,0,3),(3,3,-3,-3)$, and $(0,1,2,-2)$ are linearly dependent. Note that $$(1,2,-1,1)=2(-1,-1,0,3)+(3,3,-3,-3)+(0,1,2,-2).$$

Comment: You have made another mistake: $2x-u=-y-z\Leftrightarrow 2x+y+z-u=0$. Additionally , if you want to find a basis for $W$, you should use the property $2x-u=-y-z$.

Comment: Can you please check my answer, I think I fixed the problems :)

Answer (score 1):

Solving $2x-u=-y-z$ for $u$, we have $u=2x+y+z$. Substituting this into $W$, we get after a small algebraic manipulation:
$$W=\{(x-y+3z,4x+4z,3x+2y-z,-3x+y-5z):x,y,z\in\mathbb{R}\}\\\Rightarrow W=\{x(1,4,3,-3)+y(-1,0,2,1)+z(3,4,-1,-5):x,y,z\in\mathbb{R}\}.$$
Note that $(1,4,3,-3)=2(-1,0,2,1)+(3,4,-1,-5)$. Thus, we have
$$W=\{(2x+y)(-1,0,2,1)+(x+z)(3,4,-1,-5):x,y,z\in\mathbb{R}\}.$$

Therefore, $(-1,0,2,1)$ and $(3,4,-1,-5)$ is the generator system of $W$. Moreover, $(-1,0,2,1)$ and $(3,4,-1,-5)$ are linearly independent. Therefore, $(-1,0,2,1)$ and $(3,4,-1,-5)$ is a basis of $W$.

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

I took the solution provided by AI, that is not correct. In my opinion, the solution must be the following:
$$\left( \begin{matrix}
x-y+3z \\
4x+4z \\
3x+2y-z \\
-3x+y-5z
\end{matrix}  \right)=
\left( \begin{matrix}
x \\
4x\\
3x\\
-3x
\end{matrix} \right) + 
\left( \begin{matrix}
-y\\
0 \\
2y\\
y
\end{matrix}  \right)+
\left( \begin{matrix}
3z \\
4z \\
-z \\
-5z
\end{matrix}  \right)$$